# Difference between Rendering by import and normal in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have developed my own website and have errors using react hook.
The errors are like below.

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of
> the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

And here is my code.

ProfileEditing.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const ProfileEditing = ({
}) => {

    const user = useSelector(state => state.auth);
    console.log(user);

    return (
        <section className="dashboard">
            <div className='side'>
                <h1 className="large text-primary">Dashboard</h1>
                <p className="lead">
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};

export default ProfileEditing;
```

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import ProfileEditing from './ProfileEditing'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="profileEditing" element={<ProfileEditing />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      <Link to="/profileEditing"> GO </Link>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I try to fix it but doesn't work at all.

But If I move ProfileEditing function to App.js, then it works perfectly.

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
// import ProfileEditing from './ProfileEditing'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="profileEditing" element={<ProfileEditing />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      <Link to="/profileEditing"> GO </Link>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;

const ProfileEditing = () => {

    const user = useSelector(state => state.auth);
    console.log(user);

    return (
        <section className="dashboard">
            <div className='side'>
                <h1 className="large text-primary">Dashboard</h1>
                <p className="lead">
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};
```

Error occurs only when it rendered by importing.

Please help me.

Comment: could you move `<Link to="/profileEditing"> GO </Link>` under `<Router />`?

Comment: Thank you for you offer.
No, I don't move it. I wanna render profileEdit only when I click 'GO'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error. The problem is not because of code but because of `node_modules`. I remove `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and reinstall it. And it works now.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of things that might be wrong with your code (syntax and stuff). But I think the main problem is that your `<Link to="/profileEditing"> GO </Link>` **needs to be** inside the `<Router />`. Because otherwise, `react-router` can't handle the `useHref` method used by the `<Link/>` component.

Comment: Actually, above code is just simplified one.
I used `<Link to "/profileEditing">GO</Link>` inside the `<Router />`
It is really mystery.

Comment: I understand. Maybe it would help to take a look at a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-panna-6wo2wj

Comment: Wow!, it works. Thank you.
But I still can't find any difference here.
Can you explain what's wrong with my code, please?

Comment: There is no difference.
I copied same code in same file in my working folder.
I remove node_module in client folder and reinstall it as the same version as you share with me.
But still same error occures.

If I start from new, it will work, I'm sure. But I want to find out the error in my project.
Please help me.